# Get a submitted value from front end post form for single template

Tags: plugins, posts, front-end

I'm using [Wordpress Form Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-form-manager/) to allow users to post from the front end and I need to place values for the post in different spots in a single post template. The code they offered doesn't return anything in or outside the loop. For instance I need to put the url of the file upload into a script to play a song. The [tutorial](http://www.campbellhoffman.com/question/customize-the-e-mail-notifications/) says use this function but it doesnt return anything. Anyone have any experience with it?

```
<?php fm_summary_get_item_value('song-mp3'); ?>
```

Update: Still stressing over this. I tried something I found in a thread that somebody said allowed them to turn a value into a custom field but it doesn't seem to work the way I have it.

```
 function my_custom_field($postID) {
$my_custom_field_value_var = fm_summary_get_item_value('song-mp3');
$my_get_lastID = wp_get_recent_posts('1');
$my_thePostID = $my_get_lastID['0']['ID'];
add_post_meta($my_thePostID, 'song_mp3', $my_custom_field_value_var, true);
}
add_action('fm_form_submission', 'my_custom_field');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this..

http://www.campbellhoffman.com/form-manager-faq/#putting-submission-data-on-a-post-or-page

Comment: Yeah I saw that but it actually returns a list of all submitted date for that form which I dont understand the point of. So if you call a value for say the title...then you get a list of all the titles submitted with that form.